# Interface being deleted

Tags: dhcp, centos7

I have a cluster consisting of CentOS6.5 and CentOS7 virtual machines. I've come across an issue where the network interface, eth0, is being deleted for reasons unknown and I'm looking for help on how I can troubleshoot this and figure out what is causing it.

In the logs, I see the following:

```
2890545:Apr 30 10:59:50 nginx-web ntpd[600]: Deleting interface #4 eth0, xxx.xx.xxx.xxx#123, interface stats: received=644, sent=644, dropped=0, active_time=86400 secs
2890726-Apr 30 10:59:50 nginx-web ntpd[600]: 10.65.72.23 interface xxx.xx.xxx.xxx -> (none)
2890831-Apr 30 10:59:50 nginx-web ntpd[600]: 10.65.72.22 interface xxx.xx.xxx.xxx -> (none)
2890936-Apr 30 10:59:50 nginx-web ntpd[600]: 10.65.72.21 interface xxx.xx.xxx.xxx -> (none)
```

This seems to line up with the DHCP lease expiring as I see this roughly 24 hours before the event:

```
Apr 29 10:59:45 nginx-web dhclient[693]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x43441f77)
Apr 29 10:59:45 nginx-web dhclient[693]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x43441f77)
Apr 29 10:59:45 nginx-web dhclient[693]: DHCPOFFER from xxx.xx.xxx.x
Apr 29 10:59:45 nginx-web dhclient[693]: DHCPACK from xxx.xx.xxx.x (xid=0x43441f77)
Apr 29 10:59:47 nginx-web NET[803]: /usr/sbin/dhclient-script : updated /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 29 10:59:47 nginx-web dhclient[693]: bound to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx -- renewal in 35453 seconds.
```

The issue is only affecting our CentOS7 VMs.

We first noticed that the avahi-daemon was initially deleting the interface and thought this might be the issue, however, after disabling that service, the ntpd service deletes the interface now instead, so I suspect this is dhcp related.

Comment: ntp sounds more like a symptom can the cause.  More likely your server is having trouble renewing the lease on that interface and ntp is just reporting that fact.  Have you investigated the renewals on the DHCP server?

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's not ntpd itself causing this and probably something to do with the lease. In the first line where the interface is deleted, there is a field "active_time=86400 secs", I'm wondering if this indicates how long the interface was active before it was deleted. If so, I suspect the lease expires and never renews as it should. Also wondering why this only affects our CentOS 7 vms in the same network, and not the CentOS 6.5. Guessing there are some settings that may need to be updated differently.

Comment: See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/261123   yes the ntpd messages just mean ntpd has noticed the interface has been deleted by something else. 
"These messages are a reaction to interfaces being added and removed within the underlying networking stack. The NTP service does not itself add or removed networking interfaces."